# Measure an angle on an orthophoto or on a dense cloud

Tags: qgis, angles, orthophoto, photogrammetry, measurements

I'm currently working on QGIS 3..10.1, and I would to analyse my roof with UAV analysis. I have already made a dense cloud, an orthophoto and a DEM on agisoft metashape but now I would make few measures on my orthophoto.

I need length and angle between different line of my roof.

[image]

With my photogrammetry analysis above I know coordinates of each green cross.

To measure length of the red line it's simple with qgis but I don't know if it has a tool to measure "3D" red angle named "alpha".

Currently I measure the angle "alpha" with trigonometry and it's very long partuculary because my roof is separate in many parts.

Comment: QGIS allows you to measure angles. You need to open the measurement-dropdown by clicking the small black triangle next to the measurement tool.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply but that is not my problem. This option allows to measure 2D angle. I have only access on the first view not on the second. But thanks to my photogrammetry study I have access to altitude of each part of my roof so the second view is an interpretation of reality. 
I can calculate the alpha angle with trigonommetry, but currently calculation is made on a papper sheet. I just would know if QGIS has any tool or pluggin to solve this situation.

Comment: Yeah, there is a tool - called the field calculator. Everything you can do on a sheet, it can do to your attribute table.

Comment: Thanks you I'll try it.

Comment: So you also have the difference in hight (not just length) from one green cross to the next?

Comment: Yes this is my problem.

Comment: Don't understand: you have the hight or not? If not: how can you calculate the angle - even on paper? But if you have a DEM, it should be easy to get hights for every point. Can you provide more details: how do your data look?

Comment: Ok, I have a DEM and an orthophoto. On agisoft I had geo-referenced points, each of them contains Latitude, Longitude and Height. I can export this point in different data file. I'm not an expert so I don't know which type of file I should use to make my measure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use field calculator to calculate the angle using this formula, where `b` is the horizontal length from one green cross to the next and `a` is the hight difference (vertical distance, the dotted gray line in your second image) between both:

```
degrees ( atan (a/b))
```

Comment: Currently I make it on a papper sheet but I don't know if it is beneficial in time to make it on field calculator.

Comment: Of course it wil be a better solution to use field calculator.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply